# Qt: How to pass variable value betweeen QWizardPages with registerField()

Tags: c++, qt, wizard, qt4.8

I'm working on Qt 4.8.5. I'm using a QWizard structure with its QWizardPages (lets name them wp1, wp2, wp3,...). I need to pass one value from wp2 to wp4 but every time I try it, I get an empty string :(
The value I need is on a variable (QString sVar;) so not a widget and I've tried some things:

1. Using RegisterField with the wizardpage itselfs (as its still a type of qwidget) like this: `registerField("myField",this);` but ofcourse when i go to wp4 and try to `qDebug()<< "data: " << field("myField").toString();`it is empty.
2. I've see in some forums ppl saying that you can create a Q_PROPERTY and then use the register field. I've set it as `Q_PROPERTY sData READ getData() WRITE setDATA()` and then with `registerField("myfield, this, ...`and here I have a problem because i expect sData to apear but it doesn't.

So... any idea about how can I achieve this using registerField (I know I can also create my own slot and signal, emit it from wp2 and catch it up on wp4 but I would like to avoid it if possible)

**Added the solution:**

Class A.h:

```
class ClassA: public QWizardPage
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString sAP READ getAP WRITE setAP)
    ....
   public:
         QString getAP() const {return AP;}
         void setAP(QString s){AP=s;};
   private:
         QString AP;
```

Class A constructor:

```
registerField("AP_field",this, "sAP", SIGNAL(APChanged()));
```

Class A ::initializePage() function:

```
switch(m_iVar)
{
case 0 :...
    break;
case 1: 
    setAP("AP1");
    emit APChanged();
    break;
}
```

And then in Class B (Where you need to know that data):

```
qDebug() << " AP QPROPERTY = " <<field ("AP_Field").toString();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwizard.html#registering-and-using-fields):

> When we create a field using QWizardPage::registerField(), we pass a
>   unique field name and a widget. We can also provide a Qt property name
>   and a "changed" signal (a signal that is emitted when the property
>   changes) as third and fourth arguments; however, this is not necessary
>   for the most common Qt widgets, such as QLineEdit, QCheckBox, and
>   QComboBox, because QWizard knows which properties to look for.

So you still need a signal, but Qt will handle necessary connections for you and will catch your new value as you change it. You have to register like this:

```
registerField("myField", this, "myProperty", SIGNAL(myPropertyChanged()));
```

Then you have to remember to emit the signal each time you change your variable, and of course register it as a property.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't see that part!!

Answer (score 0):

This works from some but not all widgets that emit a signal. For QDoubleSpinWidgets, 
`QWizard::setDefaultProperty("QDoubleSpinBox", "value", SIGNAL(valueChanged(double)));`
This is because the valueChanged() is for QString and double....does not know which value to take without the parameter specifying:
"Every time the value changes QDoubleSpinBox emits two valueChanged() signals, one taking providing a double and the other a QString. The QString overload provides the value with both prefix() and suffix(). The current value can be fetched with value() and set with setValue()." doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdoublespinbox.html I hope this never troubles others and this complete solution, no warnings, errors nor unpredictable behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

For future me, this is how this can be done in Python:

```py
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

from PySide6.QtCore import Property
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QWidget, QWizardPage


class WizardPage(QWizardPage):
    def __init__(self, parent: QWidget | None = None) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._field: str = "bacon"
        self.registerField("fieldName", self, "propertyName")

    def someFunction(self) -> None:
        self.setField("fieldName", "Guido")

    if TYPE_CHECKING:
        """The following is for the type checker only. It's never run.
           Maybe, it won't be needed later."""

        @property
        def propertyName(self) -> str:
            # return anything of the correct type
            return ""

        @propertyName.setter
        def propertyName(self, value: str) -> None:
            # don't bother typing
            pass

    else:

        @Property(list)
        def propertyName(self) -> str:
            return self._field

        @propertyName.setter
        def propertyName(self, value: str) -> None:
            self._field = value
```